# How to remove list from textbox after removing the last list of list collection

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows application which input string to be insert into list of collections. Then, displays it in a text box field(Multiple lines). The problem I'm having now is the list is still there in the textbox after I clicked 'Delete button', but the last index is successfully deleted. How can I automatically delete the list in the textbox as well as the list of collection itself? it that possible to do?

These are the code snippet that I have done.

```
Public strList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
'add string to list
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        If TxtBox.Text <> "" Then
            strList.Add(TxtBox.Text)
            TxtBox.Clear()
        End If

        txtList.Clear()
        For Each s As String In strList
            txtList.Text += s & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
        Next
    End Sub


   'delete Button
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
                strList.RemoveAt(strList.Count - 1)
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

`strList.Clear()` ?

It's not possible to clear the TxtBox automatically, since it's not bind with the list, you just added the text to the textbox, try to use datasource and listView and bind them together if you want to achieve this.

Thanks

Edited:

In case you want to remove last line from the textbox,
You have to rebuilt the string after you remove your last item from the list, the method will be something like this

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        strList.RemoveAt(strList.Count - 1)
        txtList.Clear()
        For Each s As String In strList
            txtList.Text += s & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
        Next
    End Sub
```

Also i prefer to use another control for managing your list, like ListView

[VB Listview Basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8XKRlsN07k)

Comment: if I use strList.Clear(), it will delete the whole list. What I wanted was to delete only the last item of the list collection.

Comment: Oh,  I thought you want to remove all, so just after you do, strList.RemoveAt(strList.Count - 1),  call          txtList.Clear()
        For Each s As String In strList
            txtList.Text += s & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine
        Next .... to manipulate the whole text from the list to the textbox after you clear it, no other way

Comment: and in all cases, i have no clue why you use textbox with multi line to manipulate list or string, there are many controls more powerful for this purpose

Comment: Thanks Joe, this is exactly the concept I wanted to implement. I have tried using ListBox before but I have not try using ListView yet. Is it the same concept? The reason why I'm using textbox is because the existing application has been using textbox. Morever, these textbox will manipulate the string into xml format. I don't know if using other than Textbox can do so.

Comment: @Joe "use datasource and listView" I don't believe a ListView in WinForms has a DataSource property.